# Running scheduled Tasks on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, task, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to know what is the best way to run a scheduled task on AWS. Specifically I would like to only pay for the computation that is needed to run the task. So if the tasks runs once per day for 2h, then I only will pay for the 2h computation. So I don't want to have an EC2 instance running all the time, when the task is not running.

Could an AWS expert please explain how to realize this on AWS?

Comment: The answer is really dependent on what kind of task you are running. Can it be done in Lambda (with Step Functions if needed)? Does it need to run on EC2? Does it need to run at a specific time, or just need to run every so often (say daily, but at any time)?

Comment: Hi, this does not apear to be a programming question so it not appropriate for this site. Please try another more suitable stack exchange forum.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I need cron like scheduling, but only pay for the time the computation takes. I don't want to start an EC2 instance running a task and then have to stop it and starting the next day again. How is this realized? The actual Task cannot be handled by a aws with Lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS ECS Scheduled Tasks is perfect solution for you. You can run ECS Tasks on top on AWS Fargate, so, you don't need to provision any EC2 instances. It's complete Serverless solution with simple type of configuration.

Related information:

- [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs)
- [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/)
- [Scheduling Amazon ECS Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html)

Also you can just run and stop EC2 instances by AWS CloudWatch Event (cron scheduler)

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer. I'm not really getting through it aws fargate, do you only pay for the time the the task is running or do you pay for the time instance is running? I don't want to write a Script staging and terminating EC2 instances, the main point is to automatically start and stop tasks that run and I am only paying for the time the task is running.

Comment: The problem that I have with Aws fargate, is that I really onIy need an instance to be alive for the time the actual Task takes. The lifetime of the container is, to stay in my example, really only two hours a day. So the actual computation resources should be started, the task runs, the task finishes, the computation Resources terminates.

Comment: With Fargate you are paying only when your task is running. If no task is running - you don't pay. Easy